# How do I use the event VisibilityChanged?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to re-run the code contained within dela method OnNavigatedTo () when the app resumes from background.
To do this I need the event VisibilityChanged: 
[Link MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.window.visibilitychanged)

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {       
            //My code
        }
```

With this event, each time the app is opened again from the background, the code contained within dell'OnNavigatedTo runs again. How can I use that event? I can not.

Comment: That event doesn't give you the functionality you want. `VisibilityChanged` as the MSDN link says, only fires when the `.Visible` property of the window changes. That property does not change when the app is placed in the background or minimized and restored.

Comment: How can I do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Visibility changed is only relevant if the page isn't in the background. Every time the app opens it goes to OnNavigatedTo(), you can make a bool or counter to check if it is the first time you entered the page and then decide what to do based on that inside OnNavigatedTo. for Example:

```
private override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     if(hasBeenHere) Repeat_Visit(args);
     else First_Visit(args);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the app doesn't come back ever more in the OnNavigatedTo() method

Answer (score 0):

The Application_Activated Event gets fired when the application is resumed from the background.

From the App.xaml.cs of the WP8.1 Template:

```
    // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
    // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
         // your code
    }
```

**Edit** : to call methods on MainPage from app.xaml.cs has already been answered here : [How to use a method in MainPage from app.xaml.cs with variable appbar pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113864/how-to-use-a-method-in-mainpage-from-app-xaml-cs-with-variable-appbar-pivot)

Comment: From page app.xaml.cs how do I get access to the buttons and TextBlock MainPage.cs? For this I needed to repeat the code inside dell'OnNaivgatedTo

Comment: Updated the answer with response to your question.